# How to show a div over a flash object in internet explorer 9

Tags: flash, html, internet-explorer-9, z-index

My div is hiding behind a flash object(swf) in internet explorer 9
I tried with **wmode=transparent** or **wmode=opaque** or **direct** with param tag and embed tag both . I use position->absolute, and z-index->100000 with the div.
But the problem is still occurring.